# How to read in ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) encoded text in Perl

Tags: perl, encoding, input, latin1

So I'm trying to write a perl script to read in a file encoded in Latin-1.  For some reason, this just isn't working out.  When I try to do a simple search for a character that I know is in the file (it's in the first line), nothing shows up.  I'm using **use encoding "iso 8859-1";** below, but I've also tried **binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");**.  Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong, and how to make it right?

```
use encoding "iso 8859-1";

while(<>)
{
    if(/ó/gi)
    {
    print "Found one!\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don’t use the `use encoding` pragma: it’s broken.

Either specify the encoding here:

```
use open ":encoding(Latin1)";
```

or put it in the open itself:

```
open(FH, "< :encoding(Latin1)", $pathname)
   || die "can't open $pathname: $!";
```

or `binmode` it after opening:

```
binmode(FH, ":encoding(Latin1)")
   || die "can't binmode to encoding Latin1";
```

If you’re using `<ARGV>`, then `use open` is probably easiest.

Don’t forget to set the encoding on your output streams, too.

Comment: The other issue is what encoding the script is in, because it uses ó as a literal character.

Comment: @cjm: Ug, you’re right. I just have been burned by `use encoding` before.  I now have program text either in pure 7-bit ASCII or else in UTF-8 with a `use utf8` pragma, because I know *that* works.

Comment: The first solution didn't work, and the second didn't, but if I do the second and the third, it works.  I guess I'll just have to be satisfied with that for now.

Comment: @John: I wouldn’t write `/ó/` unless your source is in utf8 and you’ve said so. I would write `/\xF3/`.  There is still a problem with the accent: are you expecting it to match unaccented or differently accented characters? If so you’ll need to NFD and deMark it.